# filter some cgridview fields with print out extension?(edit,delete,view)

Tags: php, printing, yii, frameworks

I wanna print my cgridview,without header,footer,and ...
so I found print out extension witch use @media print and give you a print preview.
but I need to filter some fields like the last column(edit,delete,update).
I don't wanna to see them in print preview.
is there any solution?
(sorry because of my English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to do this with css, you have to write your own css, and make these button to not show up in printing, like:

```
@media print
{
    .button-column{
       display: none;
    }
}
```

my buttons are in class button-column, if yours are different, you should use a css selector to match your buttons td.